# NodeJS change ./node_modules/.bin location in package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json

I'm trying to change where the executes of my package's dependancies are symlinked to when installing. Is there an option I can put in the package.json to do this?

e.g. If my package has a dependancy of gulp it currently creates a symlink to the gulp executable in ./node_modules/.bin but I'd rather have the symlink created in ./bin

Is this possible?

Comment: Trying to change the path of nested dependencies before it is installed is not easy, not that I know of. However once installed you can move it (re-arrange) by using the npm-dedupe and or the flatten-packages package.

Comment: it's more I want the symlinks created in a different directory, I guess I could make a post install script to move the symlinks but it'd be kind of annoying. It's something that php/composer does so I was hoping maybe npm would be easier